# how to pop multidimensional array by going to each element

Tags: javascript

i wanted to `pop` each element one by one **let say** i have this `array [[1,2],[3]]`

i will `pop` first time by going to inside array element 1, then 2 (since 2 is last element i want to notify or log saying it is last element)

**Question**: i want to `pop` each `array` one by one if last element of each `array` encountered then i want to notify(`console.log('last element')`)

**here is the code i was trying:**

```js
var mulA = [[1,2],['a','b','c'],['s'],['g','h'],['rr','tt','mm'],[],['q']];



var intId = setInterval(function(){
    
  var poped =  mulA.pop();
  
  console.log(poped);
  
  console.log('notify on pop of each array last element');

},1500);
```

Comment: What are  you trying to achieve?why are you using set interval for this?

Comment: Check the length, if 1, last element

Comment: @amrendersingh, i cannot post my whole code , i'm just emulating actual functionality by using `setInterval`

Comment: the problem with the above `code` is it is `poping` whole `array` instead of each item one by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could chekc the lenght of the inner arrays and the outer array and print a notification or end the interval.

```js
var mulA = [[1,2],['a','b','c'],['s'],['g','h'],['rr','tt','mm'],[],['q']],
    intId = setInterval(function(){
        if (!mulA.length) {
            clearInterval(intId);
            return;
        }
        console.log(mulA[0].shift());
        if (!mulA[0].length) {
            while (mulA[0] && !mulA[0].length) mulA.shift();
            console.log('notify on pop of each array last element');
        }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: can you please tell what this line is doing  `console.log(mulA[0].shift());` as i thing this line has effect on working, it is not just `log`
`

Comment: it shifts the first element of the first inner array and logs it. do you need to keep the original data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pop the array that is inside the array, try it:

```js
var mulA = [[1,2],['a','b','c'],['s'],['g','h'],['rr','tt','mm'],[],['q']];

var poped = mulA.pop();

var intId = setInterval(function(){
   
   if(poped == undefined || poped.length < 1) {
      if(mulA.length < 1) {
         clearInterval(intId);
         console.log('finished');
         return;
      }
      poped =  mulA.pop();
      console.log('last element');
      return;
   }
   
  console.log(poped.pop());
  
  
  console.log('notify on pop of each array last element');

},1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

First print the inner array and when its length is equal to 1 than it is last element in that array, And when the length of inner array becomes 1 only than pop from the outer array.

Try the following:

```js
var mulA = [[1,2],['a','b','c'],['s'],['g','h'],['rr','tt','mm'],[],['q']];


var poped = mulA.pop();
var intId = setInterval(function(){
   if(poped.length){
      if(poped.length == 1){
        console.log(poped.pop());
        console.log('notify on pop of each array last element');
        if(!mulA.length){
          clearInterval(intId);
          return;
        }
      }else{
          console.log(poped.pop());     
      }       
   } else {
      poped = mulA.pop();

   }

},150);
```